# Particle Alembic File Export not working as intended

Tags: animation, particles, export, import, alembic

I made A Particle System, which I want to export as an Alembic. But when I import it back in or into another software to check if it is working, I'ts completely different. I made it looping, but instead of looping, it only shoots out particles for like a quarter of the intended duration. Also, copies of the particles are just floating without moving at all.

I already tried using one particle system instead of 2, and baking it into an action, but nothing worked. Any Idea, what could be going wrong?
[image]
[image] [image]

Comment: can you tell me how to fix it?
I have the same problem.
Thank you